# How do i get distinct Value of a Column and summary of Column related to Distinct column Value in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net

```
1. Private Sub Datagrid2()
        DataGridView2.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Tahoma", 7, FontStyle.Regular)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = Table2
        Table2.Columns.Add("HSN", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        Table2.Columns.Add("GST %", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        Table2.Columns.Add("TAXABLE AMT", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        Table2.Columns.Add("CGST AMT", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        Table2.Columns.Add("CGST RATE", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        Table2.Columns.Add("SGST AMT", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        Table2.Columns.Add("SGST RATE", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        DataGridView2.Columns(0).Width = 60
        DataGridView2.Columns(1).Width = 30
        DataGridView2.Columns(2).Width = 50
        DataGridView2.Columns(3).Width = 60
        DataGridView2.Columns(4).Width = 60
        DataGridView2.Columns(5).Width = 50
        DataGridView2.Columns(6).Width = 60


    End Sub

2. Private Sub Taxdetails()
            Table2.Rows.Add(TextHSNCODE.Text, Textgstperc.Text, TextTxblAmt.Text, TextSTCGSTAMT.Text, Val(Textgstperc.Text / 2),
    TextSTSGSTAMT.Text)
            DataGridView2.DataSource = Table2
            Me.DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
            DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
```

I want Distinct Value of Column 1, 2,5,7 and sum  for  COlumn 3, 4, 6 related to Column 1,2,5,7

```
End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you be specifying a data type of `String` columns that are clearly intended to store numerical data? How do you expect to sum values that are not numbers?

Comment: your correct sir it is  datatype string, but as u know that can be converted,